# select all text within ""(inclusive) after : but not including :

Tags: java, regex

```
aa: {
        one: "hello",
        two: "good",
        three: "bye",
        four: "tomorrow",

    },
    "bb": {
        "1": "a quick fox",
        "2": "a slow bird",
        "3": "a smart dog",
        "4": "a wilf flowert",
```

my data look something like above
What i want to select is all the text within "" that is on the right side of the : and that is including the "" marks

what i get is

```
: ("(.*?)")
```

but it select the : also which isn't what i want.

Comment: It looks like you want to find a JSON-parser...

Comment: It looks like you're working with JSON data; you might find it a lot easier to work with a JSON parser rather than manually parsing the JSON with regex. Check out [this article](http://theoryapp.com/parse-json-in-java/).

Comment: No, I'm no parsing json, it might look like it at times but its not the same. So any json parser will not work for me

Comment: Where you are wrong is that one JSON parser may work for you, even though this is clearly not valid JSON. And that JSON parser is called Jackson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use a regular expression, you can try the Matcher.group() method as found [here](http://www.ocpsoft.org/opensource/guide-to-regular-expressions-in-java-part-1/#section-14).

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "aa: {\n" +
                "    one: \"hello\",\n" +
                "    two: \"good\",\n" +
                "    three: \"bye\",\n" +
                "    four: \"tomorrow\",\n" +
                "  },\n" +
                "  \"bb\": {\n" +
                "    \"1\": \"a quick fox\",\n" +
                "    \"2\": \"a slow bird\",\n" +
                "    \"3\": \"a smart dog\",\n" +
                "    \"4\": \"a wilf flowert\",\n";
        // the actual code you need
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(: )(\".+\")");
        Matcher match = pattern.matcher(input);
        while (match.find()) {
            // here you go, only the value without the :
            String value = match.group(2);
            System.out.println("Found one = " + value);
        }
    }
}
```

This results in the following for me:

```
Found one = "hello"
Found one = "good"
Found one = "bye"
Found one = "tomorrow"
Found one = "a quick fox"
Found one = "a slow bird"
Found one = "a smart dog"
Found one = "a wilf flowert"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    String p = "(?<=:\\s{0,10})\"[^\"]*\"";
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(p);
    String s = 
        "aa: {\n" +
        "        one: \"hello\",\n" +
        "        two: \"good\",\n" +
        "        three: \"bye\",\n" +
        "        four: \"tomorrow\",\n" +
        "" +
        "    },\n" +
        "    \"bb\": {\n" +
        "        \"1\": \"a quick fox\",\n" +
        "        \"2\": \"a slow bird\",\n" +
        "        \"3\": \"a smart dog\",\n" +
        "        \"4\": \"a wilf flowert\",\n";
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(s);
    while (m.find())
        System.out.println(m.group());
```

result:

```
"hello"
"good"
"bye"
"tomorrow"
"a quick fox"
"a slow bird"
"a smart dog"
"a wilf flowert"
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible regex is:
`(?<=\: )\"*.*\"`,

`(?<=\: )` checks that there is a colon before the prospective string, but does not select it in the regex selection. The rest selects the quotes and the string they surround.

```
String testData = "test: \"Hello\"";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\: )\\\"*.*\\\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(testData);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(testData.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
}
```

I strongly recommend using a JSON parser opposed to a regex, as suggested by fge.
Even though your code is not technically valid JSON, it would be much more efficient and you would avoid reinventing the wheel.